# How to query json using jayway

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Definition of Matched Record: When at least three fields have values of M00 or M01 one RecordMatch object.

How can we calculate number of RecordMatch Objects qualify as a Matched Record  using Jayway JsonPath? We can calculate it using Java code, but need to calculate using JsonPath expression in the project.

```js
{
  "Inquiry": {
    "Matches": [
      {
        "TotalLength": 8,
        "TerminatedRecord": [
          {
            "RecordMatch": {
              "Name": "M01",
              "AsName": "M02",
              "Address": "M01",
              "PhoneNumber": "M00",
              "AltPhoneNumber": "M00",
              "CountrySubdivisionTaxId": "M00",
              "NationalId": "M00",
              "Country": "M00",
              "DBA": "M00",
              "PrincipalMatch": [
                {
                  "Name": "M01",
                  "Address": "M01",
                  "PhoneNumber": "M01",
                  "AltPhoneNumber": "M00",
                  "NationalId": "M01",
                  "DriversLicense": "M01"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "RecordMatch": {
              "Name": "M01",
              "AsName": "M02",
              "Address": "M01",
              "PhoneNumber": "M00",
              "AltPhoneNumber": "M00",
              "CountrySubdivisionTaxId": "M00",
              "NationalId": "M00",
              "Country": "M00",
              "DBA": "M00",
              "PrincipalMatch": [
                {
                  "Name": "M01",
                  "Address": "M01",
                  "PhoneNumber": "M01",
                  "AltPhoneNumber": "M00",
                  "NationalId": "M01",
                  "DriversLicense": "M01"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "RecordMatch": {
              "Name": "M01",
              "AsName": "M02",
              "Address": "M01",
              "PhoneNumber": "M00",
              "AltPhoneNumber": "M00",
              "CountrySubdivisionTaxId": "M00",
              "NationalId": "M00",
              "Country": "M00",
              "DBA": "M00",
              "PrincipalMatch": [
                {
                  "Name": "M01",
                  "Address": "M01",
                  "PhoneNumber": "M01",
                  "AltPhoneNumber": "M00",
                  "NationalId": "M01",
                  "DriversLicense": "M01"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider another library *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Deserialization

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"Inquiry\": {" +
    "    \"Matches\": [" +
    "      {" +
    "        \"TotalLength\": 8," +
    "        \"TerminatedRecord\": [" +
    "          {" +
    "            \"RecordMatch\": {" +
    "              \"Name\": \"M01\"," +
    "              \"AsName\": \"M02\"," +
    "              \"Address\": \"M01\"," +
    "              \"PhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"AltPhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"CountrySubdivisionTaxId\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"NationalId\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"Country\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"DBA\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"PrincipalMatch\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                  \"Name\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"Address\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"PhoneNumber\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"AltPhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "                  \"NationalId\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"DriversLicense\": \"M01\"" +
    "                }" +
    "              ]" +
    "            }" +
    "          }," +
    "          {" +
    "            \"RecordMatch\": {" +
    "              \"Name\": \"M01\"," +
    "              \"AsName\": \"M02\"," +
    "              \"Address\": \"M01\"," +
    "              \"PhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"AltPhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"CountrySubdivisionTaxId\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"NationalId\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"Country\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"DBA\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"PrincipalMatch\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                  \"Name\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"Address\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"PhoneNumber\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"AltPhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "                  \"NationalId\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"DriversLicense\": \"M01\"" +
    "                }" +
    "              ]" +
    "            }" +
    "          }," +
    "          {" +
    "            \"RecordMatch\": {" +
    "              \"Name\": \"M01\"," +
    "              \"AsName\": \"M02\"," +
    "              \"Address\": \"M01\"," +
    "              \"PhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"AltPhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"CountrySubdivisionTaxId\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"NationalId\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"Country\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"DBA\": \"M00\"," +
    "              \"PrincipalMatch\": [" +
    "                {" +
    "                  \"Name\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"Address\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"PhoneNumber\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"AltPhoneNumber\": \"M00\"," +
    "                  \"NationalId\": \"M01\"," +
    "                  \"DriversLicense\": \"M01\"" +
    "                }" +
    "              ]" +
    "            }" +
    "          }" +
    "        ]" +
    "      }" +
    "    ]" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
```

Query

```
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "Inquiry" +
    ".Matches" +
    ".TerminatedRecord" +
    ".RecordMatch@" +
    ".flatten('_')" +
    ".toArray()" +
    ".[in('M00','M01')]*" +
    ".size()" +
    ".[? >= 3]" +
    ".@size()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
3
```